# Not able to connect to Google docs, error message: The remote device or resource won't accept the connection

Tags: networking, google-docs

I have started facing a strange issue on my home network.

I am not able to connect to `docs.google.com`, it gives the following on firefox:

[image]

And in chrome:

[image]

When I troubleshoot the link it gives the message `The remote device or resource won't accept the connection`.

I tried flushing DNS, resetting IE as mentioned in some links but to no avail.

OS: Windows7 - 64-bit.

Strangely it works on my office network and other networks but not on my home network. Previously it used to work at my home as well, suddenly it stopped :-(

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you access Google Docs via any other devices at your home?

Comment: @MHrappstead I have not tried that yet, will update after doing that.

Comment: Can you ping google docs?

Comment: Other PCs at my home can access it. No I can't ping from my laptop.

Comment: Have you noticed any other websites you are unable to access?

Comment: Is your Windows installation completely up to date (Windows Updates)?

Comment: When you pinged docs.google.com did it return an IP address? If so it may be a DNS problem.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I am not sure what worked.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

- Check your browser settings and ensure proxy server is not turned on.
- Reset the browser to default settings and clear history, cached logins etc.
- I would install and run CCleaner also
- Reboot computer and reboot modem
- Run a virus and malware scan

Comment: I have done all these except the first. Firefox uses system proxy, but it was using this before as well I have not changed anything in my system. And it works at my office, can you tell me the reason why it has stopped working only for the google-docs and that too only on my home network? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is the setting for the proxy server.

In the Control Panel, select Network and Sharing Center,
On the left near the bottom, select Internet Options
Select the Connections tab
Click on Lan Settings
Remove the check mark from Use a Proxy Server for your LAN
Click on OK to exit all the pop-ups

Comment: the only checkbox that is checked in LAN settings is `Automatically detect settings` other two are unchecked including `Use proxy server for your LAN`. So I don't think this is the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible an anti-malware application or your windows firewall is causing the problem. Try disabling your firewall and antivirus temporally to see if this is the case.

Do a full malware scan of your laptop before disabling your firewall and anti-malware application just to be safe.

It's also possible but unlikely that your routers firewall is blocking your connection to docs.google.com for just your laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the time. it seems to be resolved but I am not sure what resolved it. Windows update, CCleaner registry cleanup, uninstall of a few softwares.